# How to use _.pluck function to get the values of attributes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I'd like to use the pluck function to extract value from a list of items. In the chrome javascript console, my list looks like this:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
  0: Object
     $$hashKey: "004"
     _id: "531e2252b0895bcfb8114e8b"
     country: "United States"
     __proto__: Object
  1: Object
  2: Object
  3: Object
  4: Object
  length: 5
  __proto__: Array[0]
```

I have tried using _`.pluck(myArray, country)` to extract the list of countries but its not working.
How can I use pluck to get `['United States', ....]` ?

Many thanks

Comment: Pro tip: read the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) next time. There is an example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the attribute name as a string, like this

```
_.pluck(myArray, "country");
```

For example,

```
var myArray = [{"country": "United States"}, {"country": "United Kingdom"},
               {"country": "India"}];

console.log(_.pluck(myArray, "country"));
# [ 'United States', 'United Kingdom', 'India' ]
```